# Which is the best way to name namespace and class

Tags: php, namespaces, naming-conventions, classname

1) A Namespace **"Domain\Customer"** with a Class **"Model"**

```
namespace MyDomain\Customer;
class Model { }
class Repository { }

namespace MyDomain\City;
class Model { }
class Repository { }
```

2) A Namespace **"MyDomain"** with a class **"CustomerModel"** ?

```
namespace MyDomain;
class CustomerModel { }
class CustomerRepository { }

namespace MyDomain;
class CityModel { }
class CityRepository { }
```

3) A Namespace **"MyDomain\Customer"** with a class **"CustomerModel"** ?

```
namespace MyDomain\Customer;
class CustomerModel { }
class CustomerRepository { }

namespace MyDomain\City;
class CityModel { }
class CityRepository { }
```

Or ...

Our current environment use a PHP auto-load function that include file this way

```
$o = new MyDomain\Customer\Model.php
```

Will load the file

```
MyDomain\Customer\Model.php
```

Actually where I work we use example #1 that cause all file to be named Model.php. It's a bit hard to to know what model is open without looking full path in Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class names should express what they represent. A class called `Model` sounds like if it is a general class for certain models. `CustomerModel`, in contrast, says that it is the model of a customer. *Customer* also is not clearly defined when you see it out of the context, but in your particular application, the meaning is clear. So I would suggest to chose `CustomerModel`.

If you only have `Model` and `Repository` classes, it wouldn't be good to declare a whole namespace only for those two classes, especially when you would define several two-class namespaces. Maybe separate the models from the repositories?

Comment: Yes it's probably a good idea to separate the models from the repositories because all repository class should implement the storage specific logic. Thank you for your answer.